# How to send an array of struct between two view controllers?

Tags: swift, xcode

Im trying to send an array "ranking" of Struct between two VC after tapping the "rankingButton". I don't know what to code in the second vc to get and manipulate the array.

First VC:

```
struct TopPoint{
   let user: String
   let points: Int
   var position: Int
} 

var ranking: [TopPoint] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let user1 = TopPoint(user: "fran", points: 1324, position: 1)
    ranking.append(user1)
}

@IBAction func rankingButton(_ sender: Any) {
    let vc = TopUserTableViewController(nibName:    "TopUserTableViewController", bundle: nil)
    vc.ranking = ranking
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

Second VC:

```
class TopUserTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var ranking = [TopPoint]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    //what to code to get the array?

}
```

Comment: you'll get the array in `viewDidLoad` no more

Comment: You have it. In the second vc you create the ranking property [an empty array] during initialization.  In the first VC you then update ranking to point to the new data. If you have error, or unexpected results, please share the code and error messages.

Comment: @Sh_Khan in viewDidLoad the array is empty, I don't get the data.

Comment: @Mozahler I still don't get it. If I do this in the second vc nothing is printed cuz the array is empty:                                                                                       override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ranking.forEach { (element) in 
            print(element.user)
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

Once your `secondVC` pushed, you can directly access the array in the `secondVC`. Because you set its `ranking` property equal to `ranking` in the `firstVC` For example consider having a method to iterate through array elements and print user of each struct element inside your array. You can do it by:

```
class TopUserTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var ranking: [TopPoint]!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        iterateElements()
    }

    func iterateElements() {
        ranking.forEach { (element) in 
            print(element.user)
        }
    }

}
```

You could also access directly inside your `viewDidLoad`, I added `iterateElements` method as reference, access directly in viewDidLoad as:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ranking.forEach { (element) in 
            print(element.user)
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried that before but doesn't work, nothing is printed cuz in viewDidLoad the array is empty.

Comment: See my edited answer, In your secondVC you need to declare your array as: 

var ranking: [TopPoint]!

Comment: Now I get Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value, in line: "ranking.forEach { (element) in"

Comment: Then there seem to be a problem in the way you initialize your VC, did you set TopUserTableViewController as your nib's file in nib?

Comment: I don't really know what is nib :(

Comment: let vc = TopUserTableViewController(nibName: "TopUserTableViewController", bundle: nil)

Answer (score 0):

viewDidLoad() is too early in the lifecycle. Just move your code:

```
   func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        ranking.forEach { (element) in print(element.user) } }
    }
```

Comment: So I have this code now in the second vc but im getting an error https://demo.firepad.io/#gvW6pTojeX